# Custom Validation Laravel multiple attributes 5.5

Tags: laravel, validation

In my form I have 2 attributes that need to be unique, I am trying to use Laravels Validator to do this but am very stuck..

Even if i add a `return false/true` to the function, there are no errors generated and the controller continues on. Am I missing something (not according to their docs :| )

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'organisationid' => 'required',
        'membershipcode' => 'required'
    ]);

    $validator->sometimes('membershipcode', 'required', function($input) {
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: We are not clear with your info, Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

In the store method in your controller, you can add validation like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'        => 'required|unique',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $movie = Model::create($request->all());

        return redirect('view')->with('message', 'Added successfully');
    }
```

The available validation rules are here:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules